# LZW Compression - A modified version

Tags: java, compression, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, lzw

I have an LZW algorithm -

```
private void start(int maxNumBits) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Beginning");
    /** Compress a string to a list of output symbols. */
    // Build the dictionary.
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        dict.put("" + (char)i, i);
    int i;
    String w = "";
    int bitsRead = 0;
    int bitsOutput = 0;
    int trieLength = 0;
    float lastCr = 0f;
    while((i = reader.read()) != EOF){
        bitsRead += 8;
        float currentCr = (float)bitsRead / (float)bitsOutput;
        if(bytesRead % 1024 == 0)
            System.out.println(currentCr);
        String wi = w + (char)i;
        if (dict.containsKey(wi) && ((currentCr >= lastCr) || (trieLength < maxNumBits))){
            w = wi;
            trieLength += 8;
        }
        else {
            fos.write(dict.get(w));
            bitsOutput += 8;
            // Add wi to the dictionary.
            dict.put(wi, mapSize++);
            w = "" + (char)i;
            trieLength = 0;
        }
        lastCr = currentCr;
    }
    // Output the code for w.
    if (!w.equals("")){
        fos.write(dict.get(w));
        bitsOutput += 8;
    }
}
```

where `maxNumBits` is supposed to be the maximum size of the trie. Assume the exception is caught in a main class which passes the `maxNumBits` parameter. Assume `dict` is a `HashMap`, `reader` is a `FileInputStream` and `fos` is a `FileOutputStream`.

In my version, if the trie becomes full ( that is, `trieLength > maxNumBits` ), the compression continues until the current compression ratio (`currentCr`) is less than the last compression ratio (`lastCr`).

I've run this on a ~8mb file and changing the trie length doesn't do anything to the cumulative compression ratio. Is this code

```
if(dict.containsKey(wi) && ((currentCr >= lastCr)||(trieLength < maxNumBits)))
```

correct for the requirements described?

Thanks for your help,

Sam

edit - thanks for the help with formatting, Edward

Comment: Just curious: does bytesRead meant BYTES instead of bits. I have no idea why you add 8 when you only read one byte. And here trieLength += 8 is really what you mean instead of trieLength += 1?

Comment: How did you do this: fos.write(dict.get(w)) if dict.get(w) is bigger than byte value? It is supposed to write out a byte as an int.

Comment: As I understand it, LZW code should be translated to bytes before output and the way to do it has something to do with the current code length.

Comment: it's a misprint, it should read bitsRead. And the trie should hold a specific amount of bits, for example, 20, before it looks to reset the trie.

Comment: an int is 8 bits, so you can just pass a FOS ints and it translates to bits for you. Interestingly, a FileInputStream actually gives you ints, not bits. Using ints, we can safely handle any input.

Comment: So what is the mapSize? if it's the size of the dict. You initialize  it with size 256 and when you put new string there, the size (hence the value of the dict map) will be larger than one byte can hold. If you out put the value later, it will be truncated.

Comment: @SamP in Java, aren't `int`s 32 bit?  will the FOS translate a 32 bit `int` to 32 bits then?

Comment: new characters are put into the dictionary as string keys with int values. Therefore, when we write (dict.get(w)), we are outputting a string.

`FileInputStream.read()` reads in one byte at a time, so I have used the functionality of the class to help here. I am working with one byte at a time, and it is appended to a string, (cast as a char) which is then manipulated.

In any case, my code is working and the question I have posed still stands.

Comment: Also `FileOutputStream.write()` outputs one byte at a time. Useful too.

Comment: Turns out everyone was right :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the trieLength wasn't being checked for before the next iteration was being checked, meaning that a new trie wasn't being generated when it became full.